# How to replace commas for semicolons in CSV files?

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to write Python code where in a given CSV file I replace commas with semicolons, e.g,

I want to turn this: Marie, Peter, 2.8

Into this: Marie; Peter; 2,8

This is my current code but it doesn't work...it doesn't replace commas for semicolons when I upload a CSV file

```
import csv
name3 = input("Name your CSV file:" )
import os.path
while not os.path.isfile(name3):
  print('File {0} not found.'.format(name3))
  name3 = input('Name your CSV file: ')
f3 = open(name3,'r')
name4 = input('Name your exit file:')
f4 = open(name4,'w')

c = f3.read(1) 
while c == ',' :
    c = f4.replace(",",";")
    f4.write(c)
    c = f3.read(1)

c1 = f3.read(1)
while c1 == '.' :
    c1 = f4.replace(".",",")
    f4.write(c1)
    c1 = f3.read(1)

f3.close()
f4.close()
```

Comment: You'll need to tell us how it doesn't work (error messages) so we can address the issue.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. However, your question is not clear. What does "replace the commas for semicolons" mean? Does it mean that if the input file has a comma then the output file should use a semicolon? Your description of the decimal is less clear. Finally, "it doesn't work" is much too vague. What exactly did not work? What was the input file, what was the expected output file, what did you get, and what was the full traceback for any error?

Comment: Worth noting that when you use the `format()` notation, if you only have one var `name3` you can just use `{}` without index `0`! :)

Comment: I think you misspelled the varaible `name3` in the second line (where you have ``nome3`).

Comment: Also, give us a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), not your entire program -- make it *easy* for us to help you, as the posting guidelines tell you.  Remove the overhead of user input: hard-code those file names.  Make only one replacement -- you've almost certainly made the same mistake in both passes, so our answer to one will immediately provide the other.

Comment: Also, make at least a beginning attempt to debug your problem.  There are no tracing `print` statements in this.  Among your various problems is that `f4` is not a string, so you can't replace items ... and that `c` is almost certainly *not* a single character.

Answer (score 0):

The [CSV library](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html#module-csv) that you have imported can do this quite easily as follows:

```
import csv
import os


name3 = input("Name your CSV file: ")

while not os.path.isfile(name3):
    print('File {} not found.'.format(name3))
    name3 = input('Name your CSV file: ')

name4 = input('Name your exit file: ')

with open(name3, 'r', newline='') as f_input, open(name4, 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv.writer(f_output, delimiter=';').writerows(csv.reader(f_input))
```

By default a `csv.reader()` will read comma delimited rows. A `csv.writer()` can then be used to write all the rows using `;` as the delimiter.